# Is there an app for searching Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, search, app-request

I was thinking about how I often use the Stack Overflow "ask a question" area as a search engine, rather than searching Google first. I know I'm more likely to find my answer by doing this. I was wondering if anyone has built a desktop (tab-bar) quick search? That would be a lot more convenient and efficient for me. If not, I would probably start building one.